# @Html.DisplayFor Strongly Type helper class

Tags: asp.net, razor

I am trying to display different messages based on Data
like if Isonline ==True then display on View 'Online' else 'Offline'

Code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ApplicationUsers.IsOnline_A)
}
```

but i want to change it like

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ApplicationUsers.IsOnline_A) == true
<span> Online<span>
}
else{
<span> Offline<span>
}
```

how is it done??
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `if` condition and check the property value and conditionally render your spans

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if(item.ApplicationUsers.IsOnline_A)
   {
       @:<span> Online<span>
   }
   else
   {
       @:<span> Offline<span>
   }
}
```

The `@:` expression allow us to mix plain text/html inside the C# code block. Another option is to use `<text>` block to wrap your text/html content.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   if(item.ApplicationUsers.IsOnline_A)
   {
       <text><span> Online<span></text>
   }
   else
   {
       <text><span> Offline<span></text>
   }
}
```

Assuming `IsOnline_A` is a boolean type property.